# Separate block creating for each transaction in IBM-Bluemix Hyperledger Fabric V0.6

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have created a **Blockchain** service in my [**IBM-Bluemix**](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain) account and deployed my chaincode successfully.

As a test, my chaincode simply creating and fetching the Assets using **stub.PutState** and **stub.getState**. 
But while checking the **Blockchain** tab in **dashboard**, I can see, for each ***transaction*** it is creating a separate ***block*** for deploy and invoke operations as below.

[image]

1. Why it is not adding multiple transactions into same block and when it is considering transactions into a single block?
2. How these blocks from 4 to 6 coming which does not have any contents? is it coming because of any errors?

I have gone through the [Bluemix Doc](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/etn_hsn.html#etn_overview), but didn't get a clear idea about this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the "empty" blocks although likely they reflect the fact that there was an error in the transaction(s) in those specific blocks.

In terms of the number of transactions per block, there are two factors which determine this:
- batch size - the maximum number of transactions per block
- batch interval - the maximum time between blocks if the batch size is not met

I believe that we use batch size = 500 and batch interval = 1 sec in the service.  So in order to see multiple transactions / block, you'll need to increase your invoke rate.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I will try with your suggestion for my question 2. And in the case of question 1, I didn't notice any errors so far during my invocations. will check it once more.

Comment: You might not see any errors in your invocations as they are asynchronous and as long as you can successfully submit the transaction you'll get a successful response.  We actually revamped the architecture in v1.0.X release to avoid these types of tricky issues with processing of transactions.  We now simulate transactions in the endorsement phase (aka when invoking chaincode) and then order the state changes rather than the actual chaincode commands

Comment: U are right, it was due to some errors in invocation. Thanks